# Unexpected alerts from Chrome using Protractor

Tags: protractor

2 days ago I have started to receive unexpected alerts when leaving the page (actions that change the URL really). (those alerts do not appear in a 'real' browser).

I have checked the compatibility between Chrome and Chromedriver, but the versions are compatible)

Here is the error trace. (You can see the versions of Chrome and Chromedriver)

```
Failed: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
    (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Is anyone else having this problem?

I have tried the following (without any success), as the alerts can be displayed triggered by many actions, but it did not work.

```
 capabilities: {             //conf.js
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'unexpectedAlertBehaviour': 'ignore'
}
```

Using `'accept'` or `'dismiss'` do not work either.

I am running out of ideas, so any advice is welcome.

Comment: Do you have a minimal test example and a website that makes the issue occur?

Comment: What do you mean by "those alerts do not appear in a 'real' browser" ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, found few solutions: [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/308)

What worked for me is:

```
browser.get(url).catch(function () {

  return browser.switchTo().alert().then(function (alert) {

      alert.accept();
      return browser.get(url);

  }); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Michal Dobrzycki! I also use this solution and the result was the same, The issue seems to be something around communication in our own system.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try
"--disable-notifications"
for chromeOptions

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/37105)

Comment: OP wrote "any advice is welcome." - so this is an aswer